# Resolve URL in VBScript

Tags: url, vbscript

Is there any function in VBScript that returns the absolute URL when we have domain and the relative URL.
Suppose I have the domain example.com/ and the relative path home/index.html. When the 2 values are passed to the function, the result returned should be example.com/home/index.html

For example in Java, there's a resolve method which does this job. And suppose we pass the values example.com/ and example.com/home/index.html to the method, the method returns example.com/home/index.html

Comment: Is this VBScript or Classic ASP using VBScript? Because if it's Classic ASP the answer is quite different.

Comment: Am using VBScript.

Comment: No, there is nothing built it that will parse or construct a URL for you but there are many examples of functions built to do this.

Comment: Would you be kind and provide me an example link for the same. Am unable to get the right keywords during my google search.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a Decomposition of an URL adress ? here is an example in vbscript :

```
Option Explicit
Dim adress,result,Title
Title = "Decomposition of an URL"
'Some examples for testing
'adress = "http://www.laltruiste.com:8080/coursasp/sommaire.html#ancre"
'adress = "ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/softlib/index.txt‎"
'adress = "http://www.google.com"
adress = InputBox( "Please input the http or the https address.", " What makes up a Url ?",_
"http://www.laltruiste.com:8080/coursasp/sommaire.html#ancre")
result = Search(trim(adress))
MsgBox Title & " ( Uniform Resource Locator ) ==> URL : " & DblQuote(adress) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & result,64,Title
'*******************************************************
Function Search(MyString)
    Dim objet,correspondance,collection,pattern
    pattern="^" & _
        "(\w+):\/\/([^/:]+)" & _
        "(:(\d+))?" & _
        "(" & _
            "\/" & _
            "(" & _
                "(" & _
                    "([^/]+)" & _
                    "\/" & _
                ")?" & _
                "(" & _
                    "([^#]+)" & _
                ")?" & _
                "(" & _
                    "(#(\w+)?)?" & _
                ")?" & _
            ")?" & _
        ")?" & _
    "$"
    
    Set objet = New RegExp
    objet.Pattern = Pattern
    objet.IgnoreCase = True
    objet.Global = True
    if objet.test(MyString) then
        Set collection = objet.Execute(MyString)
        Set correspondance = collection(0)
        
        result = "Protocol = " & DblQuote(correspondance.SubMatches(0)) & VbCRLF & vbCrLf _
        & "Domain = " & DblQuote(correspondance.SubMatches(1)) & VbCRLF & vbCrLf _
        & "Port = " & DblQuote(correspondance.SubMatches(3)) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf  _ 
        & "Folder = " & DblQuote(correspondance.SubMatches(7)) & VbCRLF& vbCrLf  _
        & "File = " & DblQuote(correspondance.SubMatches(9)) & VbCRLF& vbCrLf  _ 
        & "Anchor = "& DblQuote(correspondance.SubMatches(12))
        
        Search = result
    else
        Search = MsgBox("no match ===> no result found !",48,Title)
    end if
End Function
'----------------------------------------------------------------
'Function to add double quotes into a variable
Function DblQuote(Str)
    DblQuote = Chr(34) & Str & Chr(34)
End Function
'----------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can also use PowerShell to do this very easily.

```
$uri = "http://www.laltruiste.com:8080/coursasp/sommaire.html#ancre"
[system.uri]$uri
```

---

And you can get as result like that :

```
AbsolutePath   : /coursasp/sommaire.html
AbsoluteUri    : http://www.laltruiste.com:8080/coursasp/sommaire.html#ancre
LocalPath      : /coursasp/sommaire.html
Authority      : www.laltruiste.com:8080
HostNameType   : Dns
IsDefaultPort  : False
IsFile         : False
IsLoopback     : False
PathAndQuery   : /coursasp/sommaire.html
Segments       : {/, coursasp/, sommaire.html}
IsUnc          : False
Host           : www.laltruiste.com
Port           : 8080
Query          :
Fragment       : #anchor
Scheme         : http
OriginalString : http://www.laltruiste.com:8080/coursasp/sommaire.html#ancre
DnsSafeHost    : www.laltruiste.com
IsAbsoluteUri  : True
UserEscaped    : False
UserInfo       :
```